# Why we cant use driver type with mysql connectivity?

Tags: mysql

Here is my code

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/employee","root","root");
```

When we connect with Oracle Driver we specify Driver Type, that is `(type-1,type-2,type-3,type-4")` -
say

```
Class.forName("jdbc.oracle.driver.JdbcOracleDriver");
conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:XE","System","System");
```

Why don't we do this for a MySQL Database?

Comment: In your example, you did not specify any driver type for oracle.

Comment: Because there isn't a driver type in MySQL. NB the `Class.forName()` line has been unnecessary for ten years.

Comment: @ejp, not sure why you call it unnecrssary. Removing that line breaks in j2se. App servers may not may not pre load the driver. In pure jdbc perspective it is necessary plus you must have the mysql jar in classpath.

Comment: @inquisitive I called it unnecessary because  'in a pure JDBC *4* perspective', which we are all in, it *is* unnecessary. It was obsoleted by the use of the `java.util.ServiceLoader` interface in JDBC 4. Removing it will not break in any version of Java and MySQLConnector/J since 2007.

Comment: Embarrasing, it worked! Learnt something new.

Answer (score 1):

Using jdbc, we do not specify the driver type in code. We specify the driver class and the connection string. By observing these two, you may (or may not) infer the type. In your example, for both mysql and oracle, you are using their Type-4 drivers.

When you see some connection string or driver name containing `odbc` then you can be pretty sure that this is type-1 driver. You can use odbc for almost all databases. In your code the sql will be fairly neutral towards db provider. But this is the slowest way.

Type-2 drivers are rare. Mysql does not have one. Oracle has a `OCI` driver which you can use in place of thin. If you use oci driver, you have to use a different connection string,  a different driver name, different jar, and some extra installation/configuration on your system. These drivers provide some extra features not commonly available on oracle thin, ex. Clustering. Some databases like SQLite has only T-2 driver, nothing else.

I have not encountered any Type-3 driver so i cannot speak intelligently on them.

Type-4 is the most common way to connect to databases. Both of your examples are of the same type. These drivers require minimum installation/configuration on your system, are able to provide common sql subset (like T1) and db specific features (like T2). Being pure java, you can be quite sure that that your code will work fine across diffetent os (_un_like T2).

As you can see, there is no simple way to infer the type of a driver. Most of the times it does not even matter. Trend is away from odbc and towards T4. Some high perf things are still being done in T2 but it is rare.

Hope this helps